# Summation problem.

Tags: calculus, summation, geometric-series

> Problem: solve for $x$, such that:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }  x^n=\dfrac{4}{11}$$

My first idea was to evaluate the series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }  x^n=\dfrac{1}{1-x}, \text{ for }|x|<1$$
Then solve the equation: $$\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\dfrac{4}{11}$$
Which gave $x=\dfrac{-7}{4}$, incorrect since $|x|<1$. Therefore, there are no solution for $x$.

I wonder if I've got the correct answer, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I don't know enough about Real Analysis to give a definite opinion.  Given that, I came to the same conclusion that you did, using the exact same analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct. In fact, you can set bounds on the formula for geometric sum for $|x| <1$.

We have
$$ x \in (-1, 1) \Rightarrow -x \in (-1, 1) $$ $$\Rightarrow 1-x \in (0, 2) $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x} \in \left( \frac{1}{2}, \infty \right)$$

Clearly $\tfrac{4}{11}$ doesn't belong to this interval.